# docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: Service Unavailable. IN DOCKER , MAC

Tags: docker, docker-proxy

I am having this issue

```
system3:postgres saurabh-gupta2$ docker build -t postgres .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  38.91kB
Step 1/51 : FROM registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7/rhel
Get https://registry.access.redhat.com/v2/: Service Unavailable
```

---

```
docker run  -t apline 
Unable to find image 'apline:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: Service Unavailable.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I have looked for a solution that says to set proxy, but I have set the proxy for the wifi.

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#httphttps-proxy-support

Still, it is not working.

I have set proxy for docker too. It is not working.

in Preference -> proxies

Docker version 17.12 ce

I also want to know if the proxy is the issue then how can I check it is set, what is work around for this?

Comment: Ubuntu uses systemd for the docker. After following the steps in the link below things worked for me and I could successfully run docker pull mysql with no access denied error from the docker registry
https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/ Senthil

Comment: Does   https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/  require that you be logged in within Docker desktop?

Comment: Have you tried logging in with docker desktop? I had this issue and logging in with docker desktop solved it

Comment: One thing to mention is, that it could also be an incident at docker. Check this site to see their status: https://www.dockerstatus.com/

Answer (score 57):

Here are few suggestions:

1. Try restarting your Docker service.
2. Check your network connections. For example by the following shell commands:

   ```
   </dev/tcp/registry-1.docker.io/443 && echo Works || echo Problem
   curl https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/ && echo Works || echo Problem
   ```
3. Check your [proxy settings](https://blog.codeship.com/using-docker-behind-a-proxy/) (e.g. in `/etc/default/docker`).

If above won't help, this could be a temporary issue with the Docker services (as per *Service Unavailable*).

<sup>Related: [GH-842 - 503 Service Unavailable at http://hub.docker.com](https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/842).</sup>

I had this problem for past days, it just worked after that.

You can consider raising the issue at [`docker/hub-feedback` repo](https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues), check at, [Docker Community Forums](https://forums.docker.com), or contact [Docker Support](https://success.docker.com/support) directly.

Comment: For those running docker toolbox, shutting down the virtual box and then running the "Docker quickstart terminal" resolved it for me. Maybe there's a better way to restart it, but that worked.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with recent Docker / Ubuntu (18.09, 18.04). I needed to update [systemd-config](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/)

Comment: To restart docker was the solution for me. Thanks.

Comment: no solution worked for me then I restarted my computer and bingo.

Comment: #1 worked for me.
I had checked /etc/default/docker which had an old password. Updated it. Still didnt work. Restarted docker. 
$ sudo service docker restart
And it started working.

Comment: It works for me just by restarting service, `systemctl restart docker`

Answer (score 34):

```
docker logout
docker login
```

This might solve your problem

Comment: I had to login with another personal access-token

Answer (score 19):

I tried running on Windows, and got this problem after an update. I tried restarting the docker service as well as my pc, but nothing worked.

When running:

```
curl https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/ && echo Works
```

I got back:

```
{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":null}]}
Works
```

Eventually, I tried:
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/22635#issuecomment-284956961

By changing the fixed address to 8.8.8.8:
[image]

Which worked for me!
I still got the unauthorized message for `curl https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/` but I managed to pull images from docker hub.

Answer (score 13):

For me I had this issue when I first installed Docker and ran

```
docker run hello-world
```

I got an authentication required error when I ran

```
curl https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/ && echo Works
```

All I needed to do was to restart my MacOS and then run the command again, it just started pulling the image and i got the message

```
Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.
```

Comment: I had the same behavior on a virtual machine with centos (hosted on windows 10). Restarting the vm solved the issue.

Answer (score 10):

It's clearly a proxy issue: **docker proxies https connections to the wrong place**. Bear in mind that docker proxy settings may be different from the operating system (and curl) ones. Here's how I managed to solve the issue:

First of all, find out where are you proxying your docker https requests:

```
# docker info | grep Proxy
Http Proxy: http://<my.proxy.server>:8080
Https Proxy: https://<my.proxy.server>:8080
No Proxy: localhost,127.0.0.1
```

and double check your https settings.

In my case, I realized that the "Https proxy" was set to `https://...` instead of `http://...`, so I corrected it in `/etc/sysconfig/docker` file (I'm using RHEL7) and, after a docker restart with:

```
# systemctl restart docker
```

the proxy variable shows up succesfully updated:

```
# docker info | grep Proxy
Http Proxy: http://<my.proxy.server>:8080
Https Proxy: http://<my.proxy.server>:8080
No Proxy: localhost,127.0.0.1
```

and everything works fine :-)

Comment: Man ive been troubleshooting this for hours! This fixed it for me. Modified proxy settings and it worked like a charm...I had a custom proxy server running on my lan for testing.

Comment: WARNING: No blkio throttle.read_bps_device support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.write_bps_device support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.read_iops_device support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.write_iops_device support

Answer (score 5):

Just to add, in case anyone else comes across this issue.

On a Mac
   I had to logout and log back in.

```
docker logout

docker login
```

Then it prompts for username (NOTE: Not email) and password.  (Need an account on https://hub.docker.com to pull images down)

Then it worked for me.

Comment: I get the same problem when logging in?

Answer (score 5):

One option which worked for me on MAC.

Click on the Docker Icon in the tray. Open Preferences -> Proxies. Click on Manual Proxy and specify Web Server (HTTP) proxy  and  Secure Web server (HTTPS) proxy in the same format as we specify in HTTPS_PROXY env variable. 
Choose Apply and Restart.

This Worked for me

Comment: dude this is very vague!
I didn't get what should i add in Web server proxy and secure webserver

Comment: For me worked perfectly! thanks!
Basically is follow exactly what he said. If you are behind a proxy, take the value from doing "echo $http_proxy" in your terminal and use it where he says.

Answer (score 4):

try to reload daemon then restart docker service.

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Answer (score 4):

```
NTML PROXY AND DOCKER 

If your company is behind MS Proxy Server that using the proprietary NTLM protocol.

You need to install **Cntlm** Authentication Proxy

After this SET the proxy in 
/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf) with the following format:

[Service]

Environment=“HTTP_PROXY=http://<<IP OF CNTLM Proxy Server>>:3182”

In addition you can set in the .DockerFile
export http_proxy=http://<<IP OF CNTLM Proxy Server>>:3182
export https_proxy=http://<IP OF CNTLM Proxy Server>>:3182
export no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1,10.0.2.*

Followed by:
systemctl daemon-reload

systemctl restart docker
```

This Worked for me

Comment: I did not had to install Cntlm, setting the proxy in /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf was enough

Answer (score 4):

For me the problem was solved by restarting the docker daemon:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Recheck Proxy Settings with the following commands

   docker info | grep Proxy
2. Check VPN Connectivity
3. If VPN not using CHECK NET connectivity
4. Reinstall Docker and repeat the above steps.
5. Enjoy

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue when working on an **Ubuntu** server.

I was getting the following error:

```
deploy@my-comp:~$ docker login -u my-username -p my-password
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp 35.175.83.85:443: connect: connection refused
```

**Here are the things I tried that did not work**:

- Restarting the docker service using `sudo docker systemctl restart docker`
- Powering off and restarting the Ubuntu server.
- Changing the name server to 8.8.8.8 in the `/etc/resolv.conf` file

**Here's what worked for me**:

I tried checking if the server has access to the internet using the following `netcat` command:

```
nc -vz google.com 443
```

And it returned this output:

```
nc: connect to google.com port 443 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
nc: connect to google.com port 443 (tcp) failed: Network is unreachable
```

Instead of something like this:

```
Ncat: Version 7.70 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to 172.217.166.110:443.
Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.07 seconds.
```

I tried checking again if the server has access to the internet using the following `wget` command:

```
wget -q --spider http://google.com ; echo $?
```

And it returned:

```
4
```

Instead of:

```
0
```

**Note**: Anything other than 0 in the output means your system is not connected to the internet

I then tried the last time if the server has access to the internet using the following `Nmap` command:

```
nmap -p 443 google.com
```

And it returned:

```
Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-02-16 11:50 WAT
Nmap scan report for google.com (216.58.223.238)
Host is up (0.00052s latency).
Other addresses for google.com (not scanned): 2c0f:fb50:4003:802::200e
rDNS record for 216.58.223.238: los02s04-in-f14.1e100.net
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
443/tcp closed https

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.21 seconds
```

Instead something like this:

```
Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-02-16 11:50 WAT
Nmap scan report for google.com (216.58.223.238)
Host is up (0.00052s latency).
Other addresses for google.com (not scanned): 2c0f:fb50:4003:802::200e
rDNS record for 216.58.223.238: los02s04-in-f14.1e100.net
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
443/tcp open https

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.21 seconds
```

**Note**: The state of port `443/tcp` is **closed** instead of **open**

All this was enough to make me realize that connections to the internet were not allowed on the server.

All I had to do was speak with the team in charge of infrastructure to fix the network connectivity issue to the internet on the server. And once that was fixed my docker command started working fine.

**Resources**: [9 commands to check if connected to internet with shell script examples](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/commands-check-if-connected-to-internet-shell/)

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 2):

On my windows 11 all I did was to first login into my account

```
docker login
```

Answer (score 1):

Got this from a network filter (LuLu on macOS) blocking traffic to/from Docker-related processes.

Comment: In my case, Little Snitch was blocking a modified signature file.  The main rules showed Docker as allowed, but Little Snitch had revoked access to a modified process.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when I first installed Docker and ran

```
docker run hello-world
```

I was on a corporate network and switching to my personal network solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

The answers are provided here amazing, but if you are new in that and you don't realize full error then you may see at the end of that error `net/http: TLS handshake timeout.` message means that you have a slow internet connection. So it can be only that problem that's it. 
Toodles

Answer (score 1):

I had the following entries in my /etc/hosts file:

```
34.228.211.243  registry-1.docker.io
34.205.88.205   auth.docker.io
104.18.121.25   production.cloudflare.docker.com
```

Just by commenting them out, I fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. List item

Many good answers above, but mine is a bit different with Mac and Docker Desktop UI. In my case, it is a Desktop proxy setting that needs to be turned off when I am outside of corporate fiewall/proxy:

```
ERROR message from docker CLI:
Username: xxx
Password: *** 
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: Service Unavailable
```

1. My env: Machine Mac with Docker UI (i.e. called Docker Desktop,
   shown as a whale icon), running outside of corp firewall/proxy.
2. I am able to Sign In with Docker Desktop UI.
3. However, whether docker login or docker pull, I kept getting the above error and I got sidetrack into the user id, reset the daemon, ...
4. Finally, I got to the Docker Desktop UI. Sure enough, there is a proxy setting that I have setup long time ago, and totally forgot about it!
5. Yes, when I am outside of firewall, I need to turn off the proxy setting here.
   Docker Desktop -> Preference -> Resources -> Proxies. Turn
   Turn off the manual proxy configuration.
   Then docker pull works (without docker login as I was pulling a public image)!

Thanks
PS. I think the difference in behavior of Docker Desktop and Docker CLI contributes to the confusion. I am able to login to docker through the GUI, and the CLI keeps erroring out without good enough diagnostic information.

Answer (score 0):

Using Linux. For me it worked by doing:

1. $ docker logout
2. log out of hub.docker.com
3. log in to hub.docker.com
4. $ docker login

Answer (score 0):

Check whether containers is enabled or not?

- Goto --> turn on/off windows feature, then enable checkbox of containers
- Restart windows.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `root` account instead of my regular user account solved it for me.

Answer (score -1):

I have solved this issue about `$ sudo docker run hello-world` following the [Docker doc](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/).

If you are behind an HTTP Proxy server of corporate, this may solve your problem.

[Docker doc](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/) also displays other situation about HTTP proxy setting.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, stopping Proxifier fixed it. I added a rule to route any connections from `vpnkit.exe` as `Direct` and it now works.

Answer (score -1):

One of the problems you might need to check is,
Does the registry requires VPN,
Enable your VPN and try pulling again.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I have a similar issue and nothing seemed to help, restart docker, disabled IPv6 and the nslookup and dig all seemed fine.

What worked for me was going to my Docker Desktop -> Preferences -> Experimental Features and unchecking Use new virtualization framework.

Answer (score -1):

docker login terminal command worked for me.

If your machine requires VPN then must connect with VPN first and try docker login.

Comment: The [same information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62695719/2227743) has already [been posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62443828/2227743).

Comment: Thanks, have the same issue when I stop VPN, it can download.

Answer (score -1):

Just reloading system, this is helped for me. (Windows 10 64x)

Answer (score -1):

Have you create a repo with the matching tag on destinated docker hub? It might be that your container image has no where to be pushed to.

Answer (score -2):

Run `export DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=0` and then try it again.

Answer (score -2):

Use `--tls` in the pull request.
For example if original pull request is `docker pull dgraph/dgraph:v21.03.0`
Use this instead : `docker --tls pull dgraph/dgraph:v21.03.0`