# TLS handshake timeout in the installation of yolo for windows 10

Tags: docker, ssl, windows-10, yolo

I am in my windows 10 environment and trying to pull the image of yolo from the [DOCKER HUB](https://hub.docker.com/r/yolo/orcadev), After installing docker for windows and using the following command,I got  error.

**Error log**

```
C:\Windows\system32>docker pull yolo/orcadev
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: Service Unavailable. IN DOCKER , MAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49387263/docker-error-response-from-daemon-get-https-registry-1-docker-io-v2-servic)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53586262/3288890

Comment: @Adiii that link solves MAC error whereas this is windows environment, I also by the way restarted service but got same error.

Comment: you can check the second link that is based on window.

Comment: tried second link too, the new docker version has not tab for network that we can use and fix the 8.8.8.8 address as suggested in the second link?