# Docker Not pulling images from the Docker Hub on Mac OS

Tags: docker

After installing Docker Desktop on Mac OS,
I can run commands like `docker ps`.

But I can't run `docker run hello-world` or `docker-compose up`.

Here is the Error message!

```
Unable to find image 'docker/getting-started:latest' locally
    docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: Service Unavailable.
    See 'docker run --help'.**
```

I've tried

- installing and uninstalling Docker Desktop
- restarting my Mac OS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: Service Unavailable. IN DOCKER , MAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49387263/docker-error-response-from-daemon-get-https-registry-1-docker-io-v2-servic)

Comment: I've tried most of the answers. But it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Do you have the new M1 chip ? if yes have you `softwareupdate --install-rosetta` first ?

Comment: I am using the old Mac with an intel chip.

Comment: I think I've solved the problem, I will post it in the answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying different things, here is the answer for Mac OS users!

Run this command.

> docker info | grep Proxy

You'll get the similar result like below.

```
HTTP Proxy: http.xxxx.xxxx:1278
HTTPS Proxy: http.xxxx.xxxx:1278
```

Go to the Docker Desktop setting >> Resources >> Proxies. Then, turn on manual proxy configuration.

Put your HTTP Proxy as above. http.xxxx.xxxx:1278

**But put "s" in your HTTPS Proxy as https.xxxx.xxxx:1278**

And then click "Apply&Restart". The problem is solved!

[image]

Comment: Did you start experiencing this after the latest update of macOS too? Like 11.3.1 update.

Comment: Yes. I believe around that time.