# docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": Service Unavailable

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop, docker-daemon

I know this question seems like very similar to many other questions. I also read many of them included [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49387263/docker-error-response-from-daemon-get-https-registry-1-docker-io-v2-servic), I tried all I can try for but still did not resolve my issue.

## my issue

I am using Windows 10, Docker Desktop, I failed to `build`, `pull` or even try official Hello world: `docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started`, it return below error, here is my command prompt:

```
C:\windows\system32>docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started
Unable to find image 'docker/getting-started:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": Service Unavailable.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

It is working fine last week, I can build docker image without problem, this week suddenly not working. I already tried the below actions:

- Manual DNS set to `8.8.8.8`
- on docker desktop, Docker Engine config > remove `"buildkit": true` in json
- on docker desktop, troubleshoot > "Clean/Purge data" > "Reset to factory defaults"
- on docker desktop, sign in / sign out
- uninstall / reinstall Docker Desktop

I just want to have some idea, what should I do to continue investigate? What is the possible cause of this issue? Any help / suggestion / recommendation / comment are welcome, thank you!

Comment: All same for me. Let us if anyone got through.
Try downgrading docker version?

Comment: More details here
https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-run-hello-world-get-https-registry-1-docker-io-v2-service-unavailable/122531/6

Comment: I Think your docker service is not up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's my own company Laptop problem, my company Laptop automatically installed a new anti-virus software recently, it caused everyone cannot use Docker Desktop.
Afterward our IT resolved the problem and this problem is gone.