# Unable to pull any docker image

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

running: `docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started`

output:

> Unable to find image 'docker/getting-started:latest' locally docker:
> Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/":
> unable to connect to 34.205.13.154:443. Do you need an HTTP proxy?.

How to fix the above error?

This is happening even after fresh installation of Windows 10 Enterprise Version    21H2 & Docker Desktop 4.12.0 (85629)

Comment: Do you connected to a proxy /vpn?

Comment: Hi YJR, I am not connected to any proxy/vpn

Comment: Firewall issue ??  Other possibilities here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49387263/docker-error-response-from-daemon-get-https-registry-1-docker-io-v2-servic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in Docker Desktop version **4.13.1**

Answer (score 0):

If you come across this problem again:

try quitting the docker desktop app or restart the computer and test again.

Answer (score -1):

```bash
docker logout
docker login
```

This might solve your problem.

Comment: If they are unable to contact the registry to pull, it's unlikely they will be able to contact it to login, don't you think?

Comment: That's correct @SiHa, logout login does not work.